# Make an active menu tab anchor when it goes to a specific section

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

## Hello,

I create a javascript code that can add menu tabs dynamically into the menu list

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    
    const navList = document.getElementById("nav_list")
    
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
   
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
    
    const ui = document.querySelectorAll("ul")

   
    sections.forEach((sec) => {
        
        let data = sec.getAttribute("data-nav")

        let li = document.createElement("li")
        
        let text = document.createTextNode(data)
      
        li.classList.add("menu-link")

        let a = document.createElement("a")
        a.addEventListener("click", () => {
            sec.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
        })

        a.appendChild(text)
        li.appendChild(a)
        fragment.appendChild(li)
    })

    navList.appendChild(fragment)
```

But when I got stuck because I don't know how to add `active` class the tabs

This is the HTML of the menu list

```html
<nav class="navbar-menu">
        <h3>LOGO</h3>

        <div class="nav-bar">
            <label id="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="toggle()"></i>
            </label>
            <ul id="nav_list" class="navbar-list"></ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

I just need a vanilla javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the active class when you click it inside of your eventlistner.

possible solution:

```
 let a = document.createElement("a")
    a.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sec.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
        removeClasses()
        a.classList.add('active')

    })

function removeClasses() {
   //pass through array of navList and remove active class from children
}
```

You will still need to handle removing class for each item in the navList so you don't have multiple active navItems

Comment: Excuse me can you write the remove class function too